# How to purge an image on Lemmy? (GDPR Data Erasure)

Tags: legal, privacy, gdpr, photo

Given a URL to an image on my lemmy instance, how can I (as an admin) permanently delete the image (and all cache/variants of the image)?

I operate a [lemmy](https://join-lemmy.org/) instance server. One of our users just submitted a [GDPR Data Erasure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_to_be_forgotten#European_Union) request for an image. The image is orphaned, so it is not tied to any post or comment. We have a URL to the image only.

Images in lemmy are handled by the [pict-rs](https://git.asonix.dog/asonix/pict-rs/) service, which is itself distinct from lemmy. As stated in the [lemmy documentation](https://join-lemmy.org/docs/administration/administration.html#pict-rs), there is a way to purge posts and comments, but there appears to be no way to purge a given image in lemmy through the WUI or [lemmy API](https://join-lemmy.org/api/).

How can I entirely purge the image from my lemmy instance, given only the URL to the image?

Comment: See also this question on [!lemmy_support@lemmy.ml](https://lemmy.ml/post/11605575)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a big problem. At the time of writing:

1. Users cannot delete their images on Lemmy
2. If a user deletes their account, their images don't get deleted
3. There is no WUI for admins to delete images on Lemmy
4. It is very difficult for admins to find & delete images on Lemmy (via the CLI)
5. The Lemmy team didn't bother documenting how admins can delete images on Lemmy

## How to purge images in Lemmy

[pict-rs](https://git.asonix.dog/asonix/pict-rs/) is a third-party
simple image hosting service that runs along-side Lemmy for instances
that allow users to upload media.

At the time of writing, [there is no WUI for admins to find and delete
images](https://github.com/LemmyNet/lemmy-ui/issues/2360). You have to
manually query the pict-rs database and execute an API call from the
command-line. Worse: Lemmy has [no
documentation](https://github.com/LemmyNet/lemmy-docs/issues/293)
telling instance admins how to delete images

For the purposes of this example, let's assume you're trying to delete
the following image

```
https://monero.town/pictrs/image/001665df-3b25-415f-8a59-3d836bb68dd1.webp
```

There are two [API endpoints in
pict-rs](https://git.asonix.dog/asonix/pict-rs/) that can be used to
delete an image

### Method One: /image/delete/{delete_token}/{alias}

This API call is publicly-accessible, but it first requires you to
obtain the image's ``delete_token`\`

The ``delete_token`\` is first returned by Lemmy when POSTing to the
``/pictrs/image`\` endpoint

```
{
   "msg":"ok",
   "files":[
      {
         "file":"001665df-3b25-415f-8a59-3d836bb68dd1.webp",
         "delete_token":"d88b7f32-a56f-4679-bd93-4f334764d381"
      }
   ]
}
```

Two pieces of information are returned here:

1. **file** (aka the "alias") is the *server* filename of the
   uploaded image
2. **delete_token** is the token needed to delete the image

Of course, if you didn't capture this image's ``delete_token`\` at
upload-time, then you must fetch it from the postgres DB.

First, open a shell on your running postgres container. If you installed
Lemmy with docker compose, use ``docker compose ps`\` to get the
"SERVICE" name of your postgres host, and then enter it with
``docker exec`\`

```
docker compose ps --format "table {{.Service}}\t{{.Image}}\t{{.Name}}"
docker compose exec <docker_service_name> /bin/bash
```

For example:

```
user@host:/home/user/lemmy# docker compose ps --format "table {{.Service}}\t{{.Image}}\t{{.Name}}"
SERVICE    IMAGE                            NAME
lemmy      dessalines/lemmy:0.19.3          lemmy-lemmy-1
lemmy-ui   dessalines/lemmy-ui:0.19.3       lemmy-lemmy-ui-1
pictrs     docker.io/asonix/pictrs:0.5.4    lemmy-pictrs-1
postfix    docker.io/mwader/postfix-relay   lemmy-postfix-1
postgres   docker.io/postgres:15-alpine     lemmy-postgres-1
proxy      docker.io/library/nginx          lemmy-proxy-1
user@host:/home/user/lemmy# 

user@host:/home/user/lemmy# docker compose exec postgres /bin/bash
postgres:/#
```

Connect to the database as the ``lemmy`\` user

```
psql -U lemmy
```

For example

```
postgres:/# psql -U lemmy
psql (15.5)
Type "help" for help.

lemmy=#
```

Query for the image by the "alias" (the filename)

```
select * from image_upload where pictrs_alias = '<image_filename>';
```

For example

```
lemmy=# select * from image_upload where pictrs_alias = '001665df-3b25-415f-8a59-3d836bb68dd1.webp';
 local_user_id | pictrs_alias | pictrs_delete_token | published 
---------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------
1149 | 001665df-3b25-415f-8a59-3d836bb68dd1.webp | d88b7f32-a56f-4679-bd93-4f334764d381 | 2024-02-07 11:10:17.158741+00
(1 row)

lemmy=#
```

Now, take the ``pictrs_delete_token`\` from the above output, and use
it to delete the image.

The following command should be able to be run on any computer connected
to the internet.

```
curl -i "https://<instance_domain>/pictrs/image/delete/<pictrs_delete_token>/<image_filename>"
```

For example:

```
user@disp9140:~$ curl -i "https://monero.town/pictrs/image/delete/d88b7f32-a56f-4679-bd93-4f334764d381/001665df-3b25-415f-8a59-3d836bb68dd1.webp"

HTTP/2 204 No Content
server: nginx
date: Fri, 09 Feb 2024 15:37:48 GMT
vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers
cache-control: private
referrer-policy: same-origin
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: DENY
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2
user@disp9140:~$
```

> ⓘ Note: If you get an ``incorrect_login`\` error, then try [a]
> logging into the instance in your web browser and then [b] pasting the
> "`https://<instance_domain>/pictrs/image/delete/<pictrs_delete_token>/<image_filename>`"
> URL into your web browser.
> :::

The image should be deleted.

### Method Two: /internal/purge?alias={alias}

Alternatively, you could execute the deletion directly inside the pictrs
container. This eliminates the need to fetch the ``delete_token`\`.

First, open a shell on your running ``pictrs`\` container. If you
installed Lemmy with docker compose, use ``docker compose ps`\` to get
the "SERVICE" name of your postgres host, and then enter it with
``docker exec`\`

```
docker compose ps --format "table {{.Service}}\t{{.Image}}\t{{.Name}}"
docker compose exec <docker_service_name> /bin/sh
```

For example:

```
user@host:/home/user/lemmy# docker compose ps --format "table {{.Service}}\t{{.Image}}\t{{.Name}}"
SERVICE    IMAGE                            NAME
lemmy      dessalines/lemmy:0.19.3          lemmy-lemmy-1
lemmy-ui   dessalines/lemmy-ui:0.19.3       lemmy-lemmy-ui-1
pictrs     docker.io/asonix/pictrs:0.5.4    lemmy-pictrs-1
postfix    docker.io/mwader/postfix-relay   lemmy-postfix-1
postgres   docker.io/postgres:15-alpine     lemmy-postgres-1
proxy      docker.io/library/nginx          lemmy-proxy-1
user@host:/home/user/lemmy# 

user@host:/home/user/lemmy# docker compose exec pictrs /bin/sh
~ $
```

Execute the following command inside the ``pictrs`\` container.

```
wget --server-response --post-data "" --header "X-Api-Token: ${PICTRS__SERVER__API_KEY}" "http://127.0.0.1:8080/internal/purge?alias=<image_filename>"
```

For example:

```
~ $ wget --server-response --post-data "" --header "X-Api-Token: ${PICTRS__SERVER__API_KEY}" "http://127.0.0.1:8080/internal/purge?alias=001665df-3b25-415f-8a59-3d836bb68dd1.webp"
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:8080 (127.0.0.1:8080)
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-length: 67
connection: close
content-type: application/json
date: Wed, 14 Feb 2024 12:56:24 GMT

saving to 'purge?alias=001665df-3b25-415f-8a59-3d836bb68dd1.webp'
purge?alias=001665df 100% |*****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************| 67 0:00:00 ETA
'purge?alias=001665df-3b25-415f-8a59-3d836bb68dd1.webp' saved

~ $
```

> ⓘ Note: There's an error in the pict-rs reference documentation. It
> says you can POST to `/internal/delete`, but that just returns
> `404 Not Found`.
> :::

The image should be deleted

## Further Reading

Unfortunately, it seems that the Lemmy develoeprs are not taking these moral and legal (GDPR) risks seriously (they
[said](https://github.com/LemmyNet/lemmy/issues/4433#issuecomment-1939172930) **it may take years before they address them**), and **they threatened to ban me** for trying to highlight the severity of this risk, get them to tag GDPR-related bugs, and to prioritize them.

- [lemmy #4433: Deleted Account should delete uploaded media
  (pictures) too](https://github.com/LemmyNet/lemmy/issues/4433)
- [lemmy #4441: Users unable to delete their images (pictrs
  API)](https://github.com/LemmyNet/lemmy/issues/4441)
- [lemmy #4434: Unapproved users cannot delete their
  accounts/data](https://github.com/LemmyNet/lemmy/issues/4434)
- [lemmy #3973: Banned users cannot delete their
  accounts/data](https://github.com/LemmyNet/lemmy/issues/3973)
- [lemmy #4445: Create an interface for local users to view and remove
  images](https://github.com/LemmyNet/lemmy/issues/4445)
- [lemmy-ui #2359: Allow users to delete images they
  uploaded](https://github.com/LemmyNet/lemmy-ui/issues/2359)
- [lemmy-ui #2360: Allow admins to view & delete uploaded
  images](https://github.com/LemmyNet/lemmy-ui/issues/2360)
- [lemmy-ui #2361: private_message_disclaimer to include user's
  matrix handle](https://github.com/LemmyNet/lemmy-ui/issues/2361)
- [jerboa #1361: UI for deleting uploaded
  files](https://github.com/dessalines/jerboa/issues/1361)
- [jerboa #1362: Setting to hide "upload media"
  button](https://github.com/dessalines/jerboa/issues/1362)
- [jerboa #1363: Add "confirm upload" step to
  UX](https://github.com/dessalines/jerboa/issues/1363)
- [lemmy-docs #293: Document image
  moderation](https://github.com/LemmyNet/lemmy-docs/issues/293)

If GDPR-compliance is important to you on the fediverse, then please
provide feedback to the Lemmy developers in the GitHub links above.

## Attribution

This answer was copied from the following article: [Nightmare on Lemmy Street (A Fediverse GDPR Horror Story)](https://tech.michaelaltfield.net/2024/03/04/lemmy-fediverse-gdpr/)

| [image: Nightmare on Lemmy St - A GDPR Horror Story] |
| --- |
| [Nightmare on Lemmy Street (A Fediverse GDPR Horror Story)](https://tech.michaelaltfield.net/2024/03/04/lemmy-fediverse-gdpr/) |

- https://tech.michaelaltfield.net/2024/03/04/lemmy-fediverse-gdpr/